# Build error using rascal-maven-plugin (Undefined module vis::Render)

Tags: eclipse, maven, build, rascal

I'm trying to use [rascal-maven-plugin](https://github.com/usethesource/rascal-maven-plugin) in a project to get a continuous integration process, that is, not depending on Eclipse to know if things are broken.
The build process with the plugin goes well all the time, except when it finds a module (rsc file) that uses the [Rascal Visualisation library](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Rascal.html#/Rascal/Libraries/Vis/Vis.html).
I get the error below:

```
[ERROR]   lang/jimple/toolkit/CallGraph.rsc:017:07: Undefined module `vis::Render`
[ERROR]   lang/jimple/toolkit/CallGraph.rsc:017:07: Reference to name `vis::Render` cannot be resolved
```

So, I've tried to include a library that I think (by looking at rascal git repo) might be the one with this `Vis` code: `rascal_eclipse`.

I've added it to the RASCAL.MF file, located in META-INF dir. The line is exactly the one below:

```
   Require-Libraries: |lib://rascal_eclipse|
```

Even with this, I still get the same error (inside Eclipse the module is working well).

How can I get this build to work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The big thing that is missing is that the pom needs a dependency on the rascal-eclipse project. With your `Require-Libraries` declaration that might do the trick.

I think you might be the first that tries to do a pom dependency on rascal-eclipse that is outside Eclipse; contact us if you need answers?

Comment: I've tried adding rascal_eclipse to the pom file, as a dependency, but the URL https://nexus.usethesource.io/content/repositories/public/org/rascalmpl/rascal_eclipse/ does not have any library inside. Tried rascal-update-site and this one depends on rascal-eclipse-ide thas is also not found. Am I missing something? Or the repo is out of date? Thnaks.

Comment: I think we're stuck. The rascal eclipse jar is not released as a normal mvn jar on our nexus. The reason is that it does not work (you can not run it) without an Eclipse update site around it. I've to discuss this in the team. In the meantime, I do not see a workaround. Thanks for pointing this out!